# Map Data Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm new to JavaScript, Don't mind asking for naïve question

I'm getting a response from API like the following format

```
const response = {
    "slaTrend": {
            "acheived": {
                "01-01": 74.0740740741,
                "01-02": 74.0740740741,
                "01-03": 55.5555555556
            },
            "breached": {
                "01-01": 636.6716854642,
                "01-02": 636.5140839914,
                "01-03": 477.4679362239
            }
        }
  }
```

I need output like the following.

```
[{name: 'acheived', dates: ['01-01', '01-02', '01-03'], values: [74.0740740741, 74.0740740714, 74.0740740741]}, {name: 'breached', dates: ['01-01', '01-02', '01-03'], values: [636.6716854642, 636.514083991, 477.4679362239]}]
```

Can someone please help? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple `for...in` loop. Try like this

```js
const response = {
  "slaTrend": {
    "acheived": {
      "01-01": 74.0740740741,
      "01-02": 74.0740740741,
      "01-03": 55.5555555556
    },
    "breached": {
        "01-01": 636.6716854642,
        "01-02": 636.5140839914,
        "01-03": 477.4679362239
    }
  }
}

const output = []
for (const trend in response.slaTrend) {
  const dates = [];
  const values = [];
  const slaTrend = response.slaTrend[trend] || {}
  for (const date in slaTrend) {
    dates.push(date)
    values.push(slaTrend[date])
  }
  output.push({ name: trend, dates, values })
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = [];
const baseObj = response["slaTrend"];
Object.keys(baseObj).forEach(function(key){
    const dates = Object.keys(baseObj[key]);
    const vals = Object.values(baseObj[key]);
    newData.push({name: key, dates: dates, values: vals});
});
console.log('%j', newData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!